# Changing date of selector to short month

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following to change a given date to display just the short month name. Kinda works..if all the months are the same. If I have months in Sep and Oct, they all end up being Oct.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$('.month').each(function (i, obj) {
    var newMonth;
    var objDate = new Date($(obj).text()),
        locale = "en-us",
        newMonth = objDate.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "short" });
    if (newMonth !== "Invalid Date") {
        $(".month").html(newMonth);
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the final `$(".month")` you target *all* of them. Instead target just the subject of the `each` iteration with `$(this)`:

```
$(this).html(newMonth);
```

Or, since you use the second argument of the callback:

```
$(obj).html(newMonth);
```